# angular 6 undefined function when using http

Tags: angular, http, angular6, angular-http

i am trying to get an account object (in json) from my database through an api (which i wrote myself, it works). The method in the service for interaction with the api works. Here is the code for the api interacion service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Account} from './classes/account';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
/* get from database:
Address: "awdawda"
CheckedInCamping: 0
CheckedInEvent: 0
DateOfBirth: "2000"
Email: "test@c.com"
Gender: "male"
Name: "firstname"
Password: "123456"
Phone: "+3161234567"
RFID: null
TicketId: 2
*/
export class ApiInteractionService {

private URLgeneral: string = 'http://local.propapi.com/api/';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

public getAccount(email: string, password: string): any { //Observable<Account>
    this.http.get<Account[]>(this.URLgeneral + 'account/' + email + '/' + password).subscribe(a => {
        if (a[0] == null){
            console.log('(getAccount() - api service) got no data');
            return null;
        }
        else {
            console.log('(getAccount() - api service) data found:');
            console.log(a[0]);
            return a[0]; //returning the observable
        }
    });
}

public postAccount(a: Account){
    console.log('(getAccount() - api service) before api post');
    return this.http.post(this.URLgeneral, a);
}
```

}

This method works without a problem. It might not be the best way of doing it but that's fine. Authorization is not important, and neither is security. (school project)

I am using the getAccount method in a loginService:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Account} from './classes/account';
import {ApiInteractionService} from './api-interaction.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

constructor(private api: ApiInteractionService) {
}

public logIn(email, password){
    this.api.getAccount(email, password).subscribe(a => {
        if (a == undefined){ //no account found
            console.log('(logIn() - loginService) passed account was null');
            return a; //should be null
        }
        else { //account found. setting sessionstorage and reloading the page
            sessionStorage.setItem('account', JSON.stringify(a)); //set session variable
            window.alert('Logged in as ' + a.name + '.');
            location.replace('/landing');
            return a;
        }
    });
}

public logOut(): void{
    sessionStorage.removeItem('account'); //remove session variable with key 'account'
    window.alert('Logged out.');
    location.reload();
    }
}
```

This method gets called from a component.ts with data from a form:
login.component.ts:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from '../login.service';
import {Account} from '../classes/account';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

email: string = 'test@c.com';
password: string = '123456';

// email: string;
// password: string;

constructor(private LoginService: LoginService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

logIn(){
    return this.LoginService.logIn(this.email, this.password);
  }
}
```

login.component.html:

```html
    <div id="login" class="container-fluid text-center pt-5 text-light"> <!--main container-->

<div id="loginitems" class="w-25 flex-wrap flex-column rounded mx-auto p-3"> <!--div containing the items-->

    <h1 class="mb-5">Log in</h1> <!--title-->

    <!--region login form-->
    <div class="d-flex py-2 px-3 w-100 mx-auto">

          <span class="flex-column d-flex w-100">
            <label class="my-2 form-row w-100">Email: <input class="ml-auto rounded border-0 bg-dark text-light p-1" type="email" (keydown.enter)="logIn()" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email"> </label> <!--email input-->
            <label class="my-2 form-row mb-5 w-100">Password: <input class="ml-auto rounded border-0 bg-dark text-light p-1" type="password" (keydown.enter)="logIn()" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password"></label> <!--password input-->
            <button class="flex-row mx-auto w-50 mt-5 btn-dark border-0 text-light py-2 rounded" (click)="logIn()">Log in</button> <!--log in button-->
          </span>

    </div>
    <!--endregion-->

    <!--region registration shortcut-->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <label>Don't have an account yet? Register <a routerLink="/register">here</a>!</label>
    </div>
    <!--endregion-->

</div>
```

when trying to click the button to login with data (that is 100% sure in the db) it gives an error in the web console, but after the error i log the account that it received, which is correct data:

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.api.getAccount(...) is undefined"  
logIn http://localhost:4200/main.js:1093:9  
logIn http://localhost:4200/main.js:1180:16  
View_LoginComponent_0 ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.ngfactory.js:109:23  
handleEvent http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43355:41  
callWithDebugContext http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44448:22  
debugHandleEvent http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44151:12  
dispatchEvent http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40814:16  
renderEventHandlerClosure http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41258:38  
decoratePreventDefault http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59150:36  
invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:17  
onInvokeTask http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36915:24  
invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:17  
runTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:28  
invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:24  
invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:9  
globalZoneAwareCallback http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17  
LoginComponent.html:13:16  
ERROR CONTEXT   
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 22, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }  
LoginComponent.html:13:16  
(getAccount() - api service) data found: api-interaction.service.ts:35:16
{…}  

Address: "awdawda"
CheckedInCamping: 0
CheckedInEvent: 0
DateOfBirth: "2000"
Email: "test@c.com"
Gender: "male"
Name: "firstname"
Password: "123456"
Phone: "+3161234567"
RFID: null
TicketId: 2
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are subscribing within `ApiInteractionService.getAccount()`.  In fact that function does not return an Observable at all, it returns nothing initially because all your return statements are inside the `.subscribe()`.  Therefore `this.api.getAccount()`, which apparently was expecting an Observable instead got nothing returned and is undefined.

A few suggestions:

- Use Typescript's type checking. You have it commented out in the line:

  ```
  public getAccount(email: string, password: string): any { //Observable<Account>
  ```

  And replaced the type with `any`, effectively turning off all the good type checking TypeScript does for you.  If you had left that in, then TypeScript would have given you an error such as "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.", telling you that this function wasn't returning anything, much less an Observable.  I would suggest you refactor to something like this:

  ```
  public getAccount(email: string, password: string): Observable<Account> { //
      return this.http.get<Account[]>(this.URLgeneral + 'account/' + email + '/' + password).pipe(
          map(a => {
              if (a[0] == null){
                  console.log('(getAccount() - api service) got no data');
                  return null; // mapping resultant observable value to null
              }
              else {
                  console.log('(getAccount() - api service) data found:');
                  console.log(a[0]);
                  return a[0]; //mapping the resultant observable return value to the first array element
              }
          })
      );
  }
  ```

  Note that this returns the result of http.get() which IS an Observable.  Also note this function will NO LONGER DO ANYTHING IMMEDIATELY.  It will return an Observable which needs to be subscribed to to actually do any work...
- You are subscribing (again) in your `LoginService.login()` method.  Note that in general it is a bad idea to subscribe to an Observable within a Service ... if you find yourself doing that you should seriously consider if that is what you really want to do.  Perhaps this is what you wish to do in this case, but conceptually I would re-think this.  After all, it is the component that you probably want to be notified of when this Observable completes its asynchronous work and do something (like update the view with some information for example).  If that assumption is correct then you may want to refactor this function as well to just continue returning that Observable without subscribing, something like this:

  ```
  public logIn(email, password) :Observable<Account>{
      return this.api.getAccount(email, password).pipe(
          map(a => {
              if (a == undefined){ //no account found
                  console.log('(logIn() - loginService) passed account was null');
                  return a; //should be null
              }
              else { //account found. setting sessionstorage and reloading the page
                  sessionStorage.setItem('account', JSON.stringify(a)); //set session variable
                  window.alert('Logged in as ' + a.name + '.');
                  location.replace('/landing');
                  return a;
              }
          })
      );
  }
  ```

  However, now I notice that your logic simply returns 'a' in both cases, there is no transformation going on, so all you really care about is the side effect of opening an alert window.  By the way - I am really questioning in my mind if the LoginService is the place you want to show that alert, but I won't refactor that.  :)  This means `map` could simply be replaced with `tap` and drop the unnecessary returns like this:

  ```
  public logIn(email, password) :Observable<Account>{
      return this.api.getAccount(email, password).pipe(
          tap(a => {
              if (a == undefined){ //no account found
                  console.log('(logIn() - loginService) passed account was null');
              }
              else { //account found. setting sessionstorage and reloading the page
                  sessionStorage.setItem('account', JSON.stringify(a)); //set session variable
                  window.alert('Logged in as ' + a.name + '.');
                  location.replace('/landing');
              }
          })
      );
  }
  ```
- Then finally if you made that last change, you will need to refactor your `LoginComponent.login()` method to actually do the subscribe upon click.  Something like this:

  ```
  subscription: Subscription;

  logIn() {
      this.subscription = this.LoginService.logIn(this.email, this.password).subscribe(
          result => { /* here is where you should update your view */ },
          err => { /* handle any errors */ }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.subscription) { this.subscription.unsubscribe() }
  }
  ```

  Note I created a class-scope variable to track the subscription so it will be unsubscribed when the component is destroyed, that is just best practice.

Finally here are some imports you will need in a few of the files I referenced above:

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

I hope all this helps.  If this wasn't a school project I'd also suggest figuring out a way to subscribe to the observable within your template using the `async` pipe.  :)

Comment: i get what you are saying, and i will test this tomorrow. In the mean-time, i am fairly new to angular and am not familiar with pipes, maps, taps and what EXACTLY an observable is. I've read the docs a few times now and i still don't really understand them. Could you explain them a bit?

Comment: Lots of good resources out there. Start with [this one](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3).  The official [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/observables) are pretty good as well. [Here is another one](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754).  Let me know if those clear it up, it can be a bit intimidating to start with.  :)

Comment: Many thanks, this worked and i understand how it works now. I do have a question though. In LoginService.logIn(...), if it finds an account it has a `window.alert(a.name)`. This shows undefined. When i looked at the exact naming in the JSON object gotten from the db the name attribute is spelled "Name". When i changed the alert to a.Name it works with an error in my IDE saying the Account class doesn't have a Name attribute, which is corrent (it's spelled as name). Yet somehow "a" is an account. Why this strange behaviour?

Comment: The reason is a because your IDE is using TypeScript but ultimately it gets transpiled into JavaScript to run in the browser.  TypeScript adds types to JavaScript, so it will complain about things like 'Account Class does not have Name attribute', but JavaScript doesn't check such things, but instead happily executes and gives you a very unhelpful run-time error like 'a.name is undefined'.  Details [here](https://stackify.com/typescript-vs-javascript-migrate/).

Comment: By the way - what this actually means is that your API is using a different property value than Angular is and this should be fixed.  JavaScript is case sensitive so 'a.name' is a different property than 'a.Name'.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I have done that and everything works fine now.